# Single line query for percentage from two different queries in influxdb for grafana

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxql, grafana-variable

unable to get a query in grafana singlestat panel for influxdb - 
my queries are from the same field not different field.
Example -
field name = fieldA

```
query1 = SELECT "fieldA" FROM seriesA WHERE $timeFilter AND ("tag1"='yes')
query2 = SELECT "fieldA" FROM seriesA WHERE $timeFilter
```

Unable to form this in a single line for the "Single Stat" panel query in Grafana.
Has anyone tried this before without using a math plugin? Thanks!

Comment: Do I get you right that you want to find out the percentage `tag1` has on the overall value of `fieldA`? And, if so, what have you tried so far and where exactly are your problems?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I have tried normal equations like query1/query2 - but it gives a syntax error. Even on the documentation page they have a division expression for separate field values. So what worked is using a single stat math plugin, but was wondering if anyone has executed this with the right syntax.